# Parse timezone abbreviation to UTC

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, pytz

How can I convert a date time string of the form `Feb 25 2010, 16:19:20 CET` to the unix epoch?

Currently my best approach is to use `time.strptime()` is this:

```
def to_unixepoch(s):
    # ignore the time zone in strptime
    a = s.split()
    b = time.strptime(" ".join(a[:-1]) + " UTC", "%b %d %Y, %H:%M:%S %Z")
    # this puts the time_tuple(UTC+TZ) to unixepoch(UTC+TZ+LOCALTIME)
    c = int(time.mktime(b))
    # UTC+TZ
    c -= time.timezone
    # UTC
    c -= {"CET": 3600, "CEST": 2 * 3600}[a[-1]]
    return c
```

I see from other questions that it might be possible to use `calendar.timegm()`, and `pytz` among others to simplify this, but these don't handle the abbreviated time zones.

I'd like a solution that requires minimal excess libraries, I like to keep to the standard library as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up with my own arbitrary timezone abbreviation lookup too. I don't think the general case is solvable as there are multiple timezones with the same abbreviation globally.

Comment: @bobince: ok nice to know i'm not missing something. i found this awesome link which makes me feel much more secure about my method above: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python standard library does not really implement time zones. You should use [`python-dateutil`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil). It provides useful extensions to the standard `datetime` module including a time zones implementation and a parser.

You can convert time zone aware `datetime` objects to UTC with `.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc())`. For the current time as a timezone aware datetime object, you can use `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())`.

```
import dateutil.tz

cet = dateutil.tz.gettz('CET')

cesttime = datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 1, 12, 57, tzinfo=cet)
cesttime.isoformat()
'2010-04-01T12:57:00+02:00'

cettime = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 12, 57, tzinfo=cet)
cettime.isoformat() 
'2010-01-01T12:57:00+01:00'

# does not automatically parse the time zone portion
dateutil.parser.parse('Feb 25 2010, 16:19:20 CET')\
    .replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz('CET'))
```

Unfortunately this technique will be wrong during the repeated daylight savings time hour.

Comment: wait what? i thought the unix epoch was universal. 0 is midnight in GMT, and it would be 1am in CET. locality only comes into play when going back and forth to time_tuple

Comment: You are right, time.time() is supposed to be UTC.

Comment: Okay thanks for verifying, if I was wrong it would have shattered my world :)

Comment: I'd check it yourself anyway. Wikipedia says it should be UTC.