# OSX fails to convert ISO8601 to epoch

Tags: macos, epoch, iso8601, bsd, darwin

I'm getting settled on mac os and some of my scripts are not working after linux. One script in particular is very interesting.

So i'm trying to convert ISO8601 date to unix epoch. 
OSX native way to do it seems to be

```
$ date -j -f "%FT%TZ" "2015-09-09T13:19:09Z"
Wed  9 Sep 2015 13:19:09 NZST

$ date -j -f "%FT%TZ" "2015-09-09T13:19:09Z"  +%s
1441761549
```

Looks fine except it's wrong answer. It's exactly 12 hours behind real answer and my timezone +12 so how cloud timezone influence unix epoch ?

And just verifying myself

```
$ docker run -it --rm trusty date -d"2015-09-09T13:19:09Z" +%s
1441804749
```

same tools on linux giving correct answer ...

I just want to understand what is wrong here - am i missing something or is it just a broken thing ?

OSX Yosemite 10.10.4

UPD: 
Just some extra details - i'd suggest it's a difference between `date` util, except it's not only `date`.

```
Stass-MacBook:~ void$ python -c 'import dateutil.parser; print dateutil.parser.parse("2015-09-09T13:19:09Z").strftime("%s")'
1441761549

Stass-MacBook:~ void$ docker run trusty python -c 'import dateutil.parser; print dateutil.parser.parse("2015-09-09T13:19:09Z").strftime("%s")'
1441804749
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the output you’re getting is the expected and correct output when you run the macOS/BSD `date` utility with those arguments. Because it’s different from GNU `date`.

To get similar output from GNU `date`, you’d need to add the `--utc` option, and run it like so:

```
echo $(date --utc -d '2015-09-09T13:19:09Z' +"%a %-d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") $(date +%Z)
```

If your timezone is set to `NZST`, then the above will emit this:

```
Wed 9 Sep 2015 13:19:09 NZST
```

That invocation is what you can imagine BSD `date` doing when run as `date -j -f "%FT%TZ" "2015-09-09T13:19:09Z"`. For one thing, even though you’re saying, put this date/time into the default format (and not change it otherwise), it’s also tossing a timezone in there anyway.

Another way to think of what it’s doing is: by default BSD `date` is operating as if you’ve given an equivalent of the `--utc` option—that is, essentially the opposite of the GNU `date` default.

In other words, an important difference with BSD `date -j -f` is that it really just means: *take this string in this other date format and just put it into the default date format that we use here— **without considering the local timezone at all***.

> same tools on linux giving correct answer ...

macOS/BSD `date` and GNU/Linux `date` aren’t the same tools. They just have the same name.

---

As far as getting `date` in your scripts to behave the same across platforms, you can get GNU `date` by using homebrew to install the `coreutils` package:

```
brew install coreutils
```

That will make the GNU version available on your OS X system under the name `gdate`. So you could then replace `date` in your scripts with `$DATECMD` (or something), and then:

- in your OS X environment, `set DATECMD=gdate`
- in your Linux environment, `set DATECMD=date`

Of course you could instead just do `alias date=gdate` but that’s **not recommended**, because you may sometimes want to run 3rd-party tools that do expect BSD `date` in your environment.

Comment: Updated the post. That was my first guess that just `date` util is different but as it happened, i tried different utils and all of them giving same result on OSX. Is it somewhere deep into some library or what ?

Comment: About python, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732872/dateutil-parser-parse-and-lost-timezone-information and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335405/parse-timezone-abbreviation-to-utc About the underlying library, see `man strptime`. You might try writing your own simple C app using `strptime(3)`, and see if you get different behavior with it on OS X vs on a Linux system.